# setting bip and fixed-cidr for daemon.json for Docker

Tags: networking, ip, docker

How do I setup the bip and fixed-cidr for daemon.json file for Docker in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial?

more info on daemon.json here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4336